# How can I extract the name of the MACRO present in .xlsm files using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, macros, win32com, xlsm

I have got a large amount of file of .xlsm format in a folder and each file contains MACRO and I want to extract the name of each MACRO present in those files. How can I do it? Apology If I've done any mistake in asking the question. i.e This is my first question here.

```
input_path = str(input(r"Enter the input path: ")) #folder path where all the files (.xlsm formate)

import win32com.client as win32
import os

file_links = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_path):

    for file in files:

        full_file_name_link = os.path.join(input_path, file)
        file_links.append(full_file_name_link)

for link in file_links:

    excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
    book = excel.Workbooks.Open(link)
    excel.Application.Run(macro_name)
    book.Save()
    book.Close()
    excel.Application.Quit()
```

Comment: Try this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18589877/how-to-list-all-excel-macro-names-using-python

Comment: Already use this code but it's not working.

Comment: Hi Mayank, have you tried enabling vb model as trusted link in the following link.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638344/programmatic-access-to-visual-basic-project-is-not-trusted

Comment: what is the error, that you are getting ? whenever you are pasting some code in stackoverflow. make sure to mention the error that you are facing...

Comment: VBProject is part of this package ( import win32com.client )

Comment: @HarshaVardhan Thanx Now it's working fine. Thanks for ur help.